# Is there and easy way of getting a syntax validation for an url query string using JAVA

Tags: java

Is there and easy way of getting a syntax validation for an url query string using JAVA. I have found similar questions but nothing with a very good answer.

Comment: Do you know what sort of URLs you will need to validate?

Comment: Hi, only the query string, for example when you have: www.something.com?a=b&c=d, the query string is only a=b&c=d, so, given that, just wanted to know a way where I can be positive that is correctly formed: it doesn't start with & or ?, they have name=value pairs, and they are separated by &. I have found some regular expressions but none of meet all those requirements.

Comment: According to the specification, it's valid for a query string to start with `&` and even `?`. Query strings are not limited to including key/value pairs separated by `=` either. It seems like you have your own definition of what a query string should look like, so if you want to have an answer that suits your needs, you will have to specify that definition in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.net.URL` to create a URL. If the URL is incorrect, then `MalformedURLException` will be thrown.

```
try{  
    URL url=new URL("www.something.com?a=b&c=d");  
}
catch(MalformedURLException e){
    System.out.println("Sorry! This is Incorrect URL!!!");
}
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String))

> **URL**
>
> ```
> public URL(String spec) throws MalformedURLException
> ```
>
> Creates a URL object from the String representation. This constructor
> is equivalent to a call to the two-argument constructor with a null
> first argument.
>
> **Parameters**:
> spec - the String to parse as a URL.
>
> **Throws**:
> MalformedURLException - if no protocol is specified, or an unknown
> protocol is found, or spec is null.

Answer (score 0):

What if use the [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html)?

```
//instantiate a UrlValidator and then just return the url validation
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
urlValidator.isValid("http://www.google.com?param1=value1&param2=value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A):

> ```
> query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
> pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
> unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
> sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
> ```

```
                / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Which leads me to the following regular expression:

```
/([@:!$&'()*+,;=/?0-9a-z_~.-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*/i
```

Or in Java:

```
String query = "name1=value1&name2=value2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([@:!$&'()*+,;=/?0-9a-z_~.-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

System.out.println(pattern.matcher(query).matches());
```